# xlwings gives ('Member not found.', None, None) error

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

Using the following code

```
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\\Users\\VASRVR\\Desktop\\rts\\aex_stream.xlsx')    
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
stock_data = sht.range('A1:B25').value
```

gives (sometimes) the following error

```
File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Range
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

I am using the code in a loop. It's important to know that this error happens like 6 a 8 times in a 24 hour period.
I currently maintained the 'bug' using the following code which seems to run 'smoothly':

```
Try:
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\\Users\\VASRVR\\Desktop\\rts\\aex_stream.xlsx')    
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
stock_data = sht.range('A1:B25').value
Except:
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\\Users\\VASRVR\\Desktop\\rts\\aex_stream.xlsx')    
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
stock_data = sht.range('A1:B25').value
```

I've been looking at the times of the errors but I can't find a pattern.

Comment: Probably not the real error, but you should either use raw strings with single backslashes e.g. `r'C:\Users'` or double backslashes without raw strings, e.g. `'C:\\Users`

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem @FelixZumstein

Comment: @FelixZumstein Are you going to try and do something or what?

Comment: I am experiencing the same error using Python 3.6.5 Anaconda with xlwings 0.15.1 on 2019 Feb. The code raises exception at `wb.sheets('ValidSheet').range('A1:B10')` in form of `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)`. My solution was to retry it in a loop and it usually succeeds in next iteration.

Comment: @etoricky I am using still a loop as well.