# Python, Excel, xlwings, ExportAsFixedFormat - pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

Tags: python, xlwings

At first, I am sorry for my bad English.

I tried to print Excel sheet via to_pdf() method in xlwings library. I used the simpliest code I found:

```
"""
xlwings print sheet via to_pdf()
"""

import sys
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'D:\docasny.xlsx')
xw.Book(r'D:\docasny.xlsx').sheets['stary-rozpis'].range('J1').value = "XXX"
xw.Book(r'D:\docasny.xlsx').to_pdf(path=r'D:\docasny.xlsx',include=1)
```

This sample I found in dev
[guide for xlwings](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=to_pdf()#xlwings.Book.to_pdf)

I tried this in interactive mode too and this fails too.

I read all answers here:
[First answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422990/xlwings-error-pywintypes-com-error-2147352573-member-not-found-none-no)
[Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858470/xlwings-gives-member-not-found-none-none-error)

And some answers in Czech, in my languaGE...

But nothing was gone to success.
Could you give me any advice? Thank you.

Comment: This looks like you may have an issue with `pywin32`, a dependency of xlwings. Maybe updating it helps.

Comment: to_pdf(path=r'D:\docasny.xlsx') will try to overwrite your Excel file, which won't succeed.